# how to add title of gene to the output in R?

Tags: r, stringr

I have 9 length strings and list of longer strings with titles

Example data:

```
String <- "ABCDEFGHI", "ACBDGHIEF"
```

Data in text file contains 'longer strings with titles' like

```
>name
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYX
>name1
TUVWXYACBDGHIEFXGHIJKLMIJK
>name2
ABFNOCDEPQRXYXGSTUVWHIMJKL
```

I use `library(stringr)` to locate the positions of each string.

**Code in R**

```
loc <- str_locate(textfile,pattern = strings)
write.csv(loc, "locate.csv")
```

**EXPECTED Output**:

string | locate | **source of longer string**

1      | 1-9| **name1**

2      | 7-15|**name2**

3      |NA| **NA**

**QUESTION**:

I would like to add the **name of the longer string** on which the "string" located? How to do this in R? I want to have the last column (that has bold-faced in the EXPECTED OUTCOME).

Thank you for help

Venkata

Comment: start end
1 1 9
2 7 15
3 NA NA

Comment: Hi akrun - I did update the expected outcome. I want to know how to get the last column that has bolded. Thank you for your time.

Comment: yes, but that is the confusion.  For the first gene, I find the title to be `name` and it also matches the `"ABCDEFGHI"`.  You showed both 'String' to have the same length, so not clear how the 'name1' is matched

Comment: It is my mistake. you are right -first string from 'name' and second from 'name1'. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  After reading the data with `readLines`, based on the occurence of 'title' with 'value', it is alternating, so an option would be to separate into columns or vectors with a recycling logical vector ('i1'), apply the `str_locate` only the 'value' ('col2'), create a `row_number` column and the 'source_longer_string' by checking if there is a `NA` element in 'locate' or not

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
i1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
df1 <- tibble(col1 = textfile[i1], col2 = textfile[!i1])
str_locate(df1$col2, str_c(String, collapse="|")) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>%
  transmute(string = row_number(), 
           locate = str_c(start, end, sep="-"),
           source_longer_string = case_when(is.na(locate) ~ NA_character_, 
           TRUE ~ df1$col1))
#   string locate source_longer_string
#1      1    1-9                >name
#2      2   7-15               >name1
#3      3   <NA>                 <NA>
```

#### data

```
textfile <- readLines(textConnection(">name
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYX
>name1
TUVWXYACBDGHIEFXGHIJKLMIJK
>name2
ABFNOCDEPQRXYXGSTUVWHIMJKL"))

String <- c("ABCDEFGHI", "ACBDGHIEF")
```